# std::chrono: add custom duration to time_point

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

The following code does compile (`g++ 4.7.2`):

```
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::duration< double > double_prec_seconds;
typedef std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock > timepoint_t;

void do_something( const timepoint_t& tm )
{
    // ...
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    timepoint_t t0 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    timepoint_t t1 = t0 + std::chrono::seconds(3);

    // timepoint_t t3 = t0 + double_prec_seconds(3.14);
   auto t3 = t0 + double_prec_seconds(3.14);

    do_something( t1 );
}
```

My problem is that I don't know what type `t3` has. It's not `timepoint_t`, and un-commenting the line with the type explicitely given would not compile. The same with the function call: I can't call `do_something` with `t3`.

So my questions are:

- Why does the conversion fail?
- What's the best way to have double precision seconds durations?

I know that I can use an additional cast like this

```
// this works
timepoint_t t3 = t0 + std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(double_prec_seconds(3.14));
```

but I want to avoid this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I printed the type of t3 using typeid(t3).name(), piping stdout to c++filt, and it said `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >`.  Just FYI.

Comment: THANK YOU for the hint with the tool! I did basically the same, just without `c++filt` and got nothing "useful" except a cryptic name. `c++filt` seems to help, did not know that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The conversion fails, because there is no conversion from

```
std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock,
                         std::chrono::system_clock::duration >
```

to

```
std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock,
                         std::chrono::duration< double > >
```

The easiest way would be to give `double_prec_seconds` as a template parameter to `time_point`, see [std::chrono::time_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

```
typedef std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock,
                                 double_prec_seconds > timepoint_t;
```

then you already have the proper type for `t3` and `do_something`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I tried to provide a conversion, but did not think about changing my `typedef`. My code now looks and works like intended.